# Are the default objects of VB a type of singleton?

Tags: vb.net, singleton

Are the default objects supported by `My` keyword in VB.net is a kind of singleton? If not, what is the difference?

Again is this "default object" feature is something useful? If yes, then why it is not implemented in other languages like C#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not a Singleton.

`My` is just a namespace containing static classes, methods and properties that point to other parts of the .NET framework, and provide some additional capabilities (e.g. `CopyDirectory`)  Think of it as a set of shortcuts, a speed-dial of sorts.

Visual Basic [provides language/compiler support](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2004/04/23/991.aspx) with the `My` keyword.  You can [use the `My` classes in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173136%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) by adding a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, but it is awkward, and not all classes are compatible with C# (they are VB specific).  In C#, unless you want some of the VB capabilities (like "CopyDirectory"), it is more convenient to just reference the .NET framework classes directly, IMO.

Visual Basic has a somewhat different language philosophy than C# does.  Originally, VB was to be the "applications" language, and C# was to be the "systems" language.  Since then, the two languages have converged, and the feature sets of the two are almost indistinguishable, with a few notable differences (this being one, XML Literals being another).

I am quite certain that, if you asked Eric Lippert or one of the other members of the C# compiler team, they would tell you that implementing new features is a tug-of-war between available resources and feature importance, and that this particular feature just never hit threshold.

**Navigate The .NET Framework And Your Projects With The My Namespace** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163680.aspx

**My Namespace** 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms789188

Comment: So, "why it is not implemented in other languages like C#?"

Comment: @Gulshan: I added some additional detail about that.

Comment: It was implemented in vb.net to make the transition from VB6 to VB.net easier, or at least more appealing to VB6 programmers. Something like it might make it's way to C#, though C# seems more attached to modularity and OOP

Comment: Though the *capabilities* of the languages have converged, there are still differences in design philosophy and in typical user preferences. The "My" feature, like XML literals, fits well with the VB philosophy of making common tasks highly discoverable to opportunistic programmers. The more "general" C# philosophy eschews special treatment for specific tasks. And yes, of course there are budgetary concerns as well, as you note.

Comment: I would say the more important reason for the c# team not to implement My, is that it's a dll, and so is already implemented for C#.  The bias that prevents some C# programmers from using it is simply unreasonable.  They should pretend that it is a 3rd party utility written by someone else in an unknown language, wher that someone else is way more reliabilty than most , and simply use it if it fits the task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

`My` is a namespace not a singleton, but the "default objects supported by `My` keyword" *are* thread-local singletons (i.e. one instance per thread) as can be seen when using Reflector.

And the `ThreadSafeObjectProvider<T>` that provides this support is generated in each assembly compiled by VB.NET and is `Friend` so it is not available for external use.

Nevertheless its implementation is easy to replicate in your own `ThreadSafeSinglton<T>`. It is effectively a normal .NET singleton pattern except the backing field has the `<ThreadStatic>` attribute.